# How to have a sprite follow another "within bounds"

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to create an eyeball that follows the user. In this sense, the eye should follow the position of the user but should only be able to move within certain bounds (The eye socket). The code I wrote below works, but its very choppy.

```
if(dist <= socketRadius - self.aEye.size.width/2.2){
    lastPosition = self.aEye.position
    self.aEye.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx:theVec.dx * eyeMoveSpeed, dy:theVec.dy * eyeMoveSpeed)
}
else{

    let toCenterVector = normalizeVector( CGVector(dx:(self.socket.position.x - self.aEye.position.x), dy:(self.socket.position.y - self.aEye.position.y)*3 ))
    self.aEye.physicsBody?.velocity = toCenterVector
    print(toCenterVector)
    print("Out")
}
```

(`dist` is the distance from the eyeball to the eyesocket center)

Is there a way to have a smooth flow of the eyeball around its socket to follow the user's position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SKConstraints to achieve this. Something like:

```
let rangeToCenterSprite = SKRange(lowerLimit: 80, upperLimit: 90)
var distanceConstraint: SKConstraint

distanceConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(rangeToCenterSprite, toNode: SpriteNodeInEyeCenter)
EyeBallSprite.constraints = [distanceConstraint]
```

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly. Seems like there a few things that aren't already included in Swift.